# Tableau SUM (IF STATEMENT)

Tags: tableau-api, sumifs

Can someone please advise on how to write this statement below in Tableau?

I am trying to replicate BO Logic to tableau :

=If [Total Received Status Count]=0 Then 0 Else
Sum(If IsNull(ToNumber( Trim([Overagesamepubquantity]) )) Then 0 Else ToNumber(Trim( [Overagesamepubquantity])) ) /[Total Received Status Count]

Tried below :

If [Total Received Status Count]=0 Then 0 Else
Sum(If IsNull(INT( Trim([Overagesamepubquantity]) )) Then 0 Else INT(Trim( [Overagesamepubquantity])) ) /[Total Received Status Count] END

The below worked , how ever not sure if it is right....

If SUM([Total Received Status Count])=0 Then 0 ELSE
Sum(If IsNull(INT( Trim([Overagesamepubquantity]) )) Then 0 Else INT(Trim( [Overagesamepubquantity]))END) / SUM([Total Received Status Count]) END